# How do I extract means/max/min/median from a subset of rows in a column in a dataframe?

Tags: r, subset

EDITED FOR CLARITY

Sorry for the previous version. In my mind I was being thorough while in reality I was making it difficult to help me.

I have several files (about 80) where I have observations of temperatures at different coordinates. Each file corresponds to observations of a species. It is set up as below:

```
dput(head(BIRD_NAME, 10))
structure(list(x = c(-4.752939, 1.129787, 51.918896, 21.512894, 
-9.319702, -0.046992, 6.38507, -7.441907, 33.9505, -3.165023), 
    y = c(42.067673, 52.03018, 47.105537, 61.84814, 38.7668, 
    51.59226, 53.170395, 37.208645, 36.302677, 40.64759), Feb = c(5.80000019073486, 
    3.90000009536743, -7.30000019073486, -6.09999990463257, 12.1000003814697, 
    4.80000019073486, 2.20000004768372, 12.5, 11.3000001907349, 
    6.40000009536743), Mar = c(8.19999980926514, 6, 0.100000001490116, 
    -2.5, 13.6000003814697, 6.90000009536743, 4.90000009536743, 
    14.1000003814697, 13.8999996185303, 9), Apr = c(9.80000019073486, 
    7.90000009536743, 11.8000001907349, 2.40000009536743, 14.5, 
    8.80000019073486, 7.5, 15.6000003814697, 17.6000003814697, 
    11), May = c(13.3999996185303, 11.5, 18.8999996185303, 8.30000019073486, 
    16.6000003814697, 12.5, 11.8000001907349, 18.2999992370605, 
    21.2999992370605, 14.8000001907349), Jun = c(17.7999992370605, 
    14.5, 24.3999996185303, 13.1999998092651, 19.2000007629395, 
    15.6000003814697, 14.5, 22, 24.7999992370605, 19.7999992370605
    ), Sep = c(17.7999992370605, 14.3999996185303, 17.7999992370605, 
    10.1999998092651, 20.3999996185303, 14.8000001907349, 13.6000003814697, 
    22.8999996185303, 25.7999992370605, 19.6000003814697), MONTH = structure(c(3L, 
    4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L), levels = c("2", "3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "9"), class = "factor"), DATE = structure(c(3L, 
    4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L), levels = c("2", "3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "9"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The column 'MONTH' related to the month the observation was made, while the columns with month names are the temperature at the site of observation in different months.

What I want to do is to get the median/minimum/maximum/mean for each month column, but ONLY for the rows which correspond to observations in that same month. Eg, for the month column Feb, I only want the values from rows with the value of 2, for Mar 3, for Apr 4... (that is why I went through all the confusing steps).

My end product would be a new df with columns  where the first column is liek the original filemane.

```
TEMP_MAXMINMEDMEAN = data.frame(filename = character(),
                     feb_max = numeric(), feb_min = numeric(),feb_med =numeric(),feb_mean = numeric(),
                   mar_max = numeric(),mar_min = numeric(),mar_med =numeric(), mar_mean = numeric(),
                   apr_max = numeric(), apr_min = numeric(),apr_med =numeric(),apr_mean = numeric(), 
                    sept_max = numeric(),sept_min = numeric(),sept_med =numeric(),sept_mean = numeric())
```

I hope this is more clear than the goosechase I wrote before.

Comment: Hi @ArchaeoAmos! You may get better, faster help if you edit your question for clarity and down to exactly what you need. Right now it is a bit confusing - are you simply trying to get the summary statistics by month? Try including your original "start" data, and your desired "end" data. In your current example data, you dont have `TEMP`. Try editing to add in the output of `dput(head(TEMP_WIDE, 10))`. Also, a lot of information you put here isn't particularly useful and makes the question convoluted. Try editing out anything that is unrelated to the question. Just trying to help, good luck!

Comment: I would recommend to re-organize the data with `pivot_longer` from package **tidyr**, so that the relevant column months are rows in two columns, e.g. "month" and "values". Then you can easily use `group_by` and ` summarize`from **dplyr**.

Comment: What is speciesname? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @jpsmith thanks for that. I thought I was helping, but I was hurting. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: No worries, we'r all just trying to help each other. I dont think you need to create MONTH and DATE the way you have. Try `BIRD_NAME[, -c(9:10)] %>% pivot_longer(Feb:Sep, names_to = "month") %>% group_by(month) %>% summarize(mean_val = mean(value), max_val = max(value), min_val = min(value), median_val = median(value))` and see if that gives what you want